# Создание svg картинок через js

Tags: javascript

Создаю элементы страницы через js, щас нужно вставлять svg иконки, делаю так:

```js
let use1 = document.createElement('use');
use1.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#edit');
```

Вот только так ничего не работает, иконки просто нету, если после создания глянуть DOM, то он стоит так, как я его создал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вставлять иконку в html:

```html
<svg class="edit">
    <use xlink:href="#edit"></use>
</svg>
```

, то в DOM-e оно "распарсилось", и картинка присутсвует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что за аномалии такие?

Comment: [document.createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)